# Python multiprocessing queue scaling to large numbers of workers

Tags: python, message-queue, multiprocessing

I have a python (2.6.5 64-bit, Windows 2008 Server R2) app that launches worker processes. The parent process puts jobs in a job queue, from which workers pick them up. Similarly it has a results queue. Each worker performs its job by querying a server. CPU usage by the workers is low.

When the number of workers grows, CPU usage on the servers actually shrinks. The servers themselves are not the bottleneck, as I can load them up further from other applications.

Anyone else seen similar behavior? Is there an issue with python multiprocessing queues when a large number of processes are reading or writing to the same queues?

Comment: Please could you clarify, are you saying that "I've increased the number of workers, but the amount of work being done has fallen"?

Comment: Can you share some code? There could be many causes, depending on the implementation.

Comment: @MattH: Less work meaning (A) The CPU usage on the server drops, and (B) the rate of results being recorded drops. (Recording results isn't a bottleneck, that's been tested, as has excess server processing capacity.).

Comment: @Underhill: Your question confuses me by talking about server and servers interchangeably having mentioned that the workers' work is to query servers. Are the workers and parent all on the same system? Is it that system whose CPU usage drops with more workers?

Comment: @MattH: Parent and workers are on the same system. CPU utilization on this machine is always low, regardless of worker count. Servers are separate machines; these are the machines that see a drop in CPU utilization at large worker counts.

Comment: @Underhill: If your workers are mostly idle, then you should be using threading.

Answer (score 1):

Two different ideas for performance constraints:

1. The bottleneck is the workers fighting each other and the parent for access to the job queue.
2. The bottleneck is connection rate-limits (syn-flood protection) on the servers.

Gathering more information:

1. Profile the amount of work done: tasks completed per second, use this as your core performance metric.
2. Use packet capture to view the network activity for network-level delays.
3. Have your workers document how long they wait for access to the job queue.

Possible improvements:

1. Have your workers use persistent connections if available/applicable (e.g. HTTP).
2. Split the tasks into multiple job queues fed to pools of workers.

Comment: Workers already use persistent connections. I've been considering the multi-queue approach, but am hesitant to rearrange that much code when the actual issue is still so hazy. (I've also considered using, say, 4 worker threads per worker process, to reduce the number of actual processes, in case the problem is python multiprocessing.)

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure what is going on unless you provide all the details.

However, remember that the real concurrency is bounded by the actual number of hardware threads. If the number of processes launched is much larger than the actual number of hardware threads, at some point the context-switching overhead will be more than the benefit of having more concurrent processes.

Comment: There is plenty of physical processing time available, CPU utilization is quite low.It shouldn't be a context switching issue. The problem crops up with as few as 30 workers on an 8-core system. Also, each worker spends a fair amount of time idle: queries to a server take about 1/3 of a second.

Answer (score 0):

Creating of new thead is very expensive operation.

One of the simplest ways for controling a lot of paralell network connections is to use stackless threads with support of asyncronical sockets. Python had great support and a bunch of libraries for that.

My favorite one is [gevent](http://www.gevent.org/gevent.monkey.html), which has a great and comletely transparent monkey-patching utility.